# Login with reCAPTCHA check doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli, recaptcha

This is my PHP code, I'm trying to make a system which only login when the username and password are correct and when the captcha is validated. But now the is issue. The code I've writen will always login even when the captcha is not validated.

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] === true && isset($_SESSION['userid']) && $_SESSION['userid'] != "") {
 header('location: loggedin.php');
 exit();
}

include "connect.php";
include "functions.php";

$error = "";

if (isset($_POST['login']) || isset($_POST['username']) || isset($_POST['password']) || isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $captcha= $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
 if (checkUsername($username) === false) {
        $error = "Onjuiste inlogpoging";
    }
    if (checkPassword($password) === false) {
        $error = "Onjuiste inlogpoging";
    }
   if(!$captcha){
            $error = "Please check the the captcha form.";
            
          }

    $secure_username = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($username));
    $secure_password = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($password));

    $q_checklogin = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = UNHEX('$secure_username') AND password = UNHEX('$secure_password')");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($q_checklogin) === 1) {
  $r_checklogin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_checklogin);
  $_SESSION['userid'] = $r_checklogin['id'];
  $_SESSION['login'] = true;
  header('location: loggedin.php');
    } else {
        $error = "Onjuiste inlogpoging";
    }

}
?>
```

This is my HTML code for anyone who needs it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <script src="js/java.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Login</title>
  <style>
  .error {
 color: darkred;
 font-weight: bold;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">SBRM National Bank</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Particulier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Persoonlijk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privé</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Zakelijk</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registeren</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>  Inloggen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid hero-slide">
      <div class="row">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">



      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/login.jpg" alt="Ad">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="caption">Inloggen</h3>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container padding-top-10">
  <div class="panel col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading "><h5>Inloggen</h5></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="login.php" method="post">
<label for="username" class="control-label">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" name="username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) { echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
<label for="password" class="control-label">Wachtwoord:</label>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" name="password" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['password'])) { echo $_POST['password']; } ?>" required/>
          </div>
          <!-- Alleen nodig bij registratie, maar je kan hier wel een pincode als extra beveiliging van maken gezien het normaal om geld gaat
    <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Herhaal Wachtwoord" name="rpassword" required/>
          </div>
    -->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 padding-top-10 ">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcCsBoTAAAAAK72uzyJSrgWwD8xuF6jFIfgFaHX"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 padding-top-10">
            <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-succes" value="Login">
          </div>
        </div>
  <?php if ($error !== "") { ?>
  <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-12 error">
            <?php echo $error; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
  <?php } ?>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
            <p class="pleft">Door op <b>login</b> te klikken, gaat u akkoord met de <a class="algemeen" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Algemene Voorwaarden</a> opgesteld door deze site.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="t_and_c_m" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Algemene Voorwaarden</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Deze algemene voorwaarden zijn tot stand gekomen in overleg
tussen de Nederlandse Vereniging van Banken en de Consumentenbond
in het kader van de Coördinatiegroep Zelfreguleringsoverleg
van de Sociaal-Economische Raad en treden in werking
per 1 november 2009. Over overige (product)voorwaarden die
van toepassing kunnen zijn heeft geen overleg plaatsgevonden.
De Consumentenbond behoudt zich het recht tot collectieve
actie voor met betrekking tot dergelijke voorwaarden.</p>
      </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ik ga akkoord</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2016</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="boss">Sander Bakker</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Bob Lansbergen</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Ronald van den Heuvel</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Max Donck</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h6>Over Ons</h6>
        <p id="pfont">Dit is een website ontworpen om een banksysteem te simuleren met PHP en mySQL</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h6>Navigatie</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Particulier</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Persoonlijk</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Privé</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Zakelijk</a></li>
        </uL>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h6>Contact</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Google +</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </uL>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
  </body>
  </head>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only save the error to `$error` variable, but you still let the script run the query. You need to add another condition before making the query:

```
if( empty($error) ) {
    $secure_username = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($username));
    $secure_password = bin2hex(htmlspecialchars($password));

    $q_checklogin = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = UNHEX('$secure_username') AND password = UNHEX('$secure_password')");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($q_checklogin) === 1) {
        $r_checklogin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q_checklogin);
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $r_checklogin['id'];
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header('location: loggedin.php');
    } else {
        $error = "Onjuiste inlogpoging";
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't know where you're actually showing the `$error`, but this is not relevant for the question itself.

And addition to my answer, to check the session status, you can also use:

```
if( session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) { session_start(); }
```

Instead of

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
```